# Is it difficult to populate a ServiceStack session with a database call?

Tags: c#, session, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I want to make neat database calls with Ormlite inside my custom AuthUserSession (which by the way, lives in a separate project from the AppHost project). But I can only seem to get the raw database connection object.

```
public class CustomUserSession : AuthUserSession
{
    public string CustomProperty { get; set; }

    public override void OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, IOAuthTokens tokens, Dictionary<string, string> authInfo)
    {
        base.OnAuthenticated(authService, session, tokens, authInfo);

         // using (var Db = authService.TryResolve<ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteConnectionFactory>().OpenDbConnection())
        using (var Db = authService.TryResolve<ServiceStack.OrmLite.IDbConnectionFactory>().OpenDbConnection())
        {
            // it seems I can make long winded calls to database using 'Db'  but
            // instead I want to eliminate this 'using statement' and simply do

            // var result = Db.FirstOrDefault<MyTable>(x => x.Id == userId);
            // CustomProperty = result.aStringField;
        }
    }
}
```

[side note: documenation often says we need to do the following to append data to the session but my session object appears to work without it i.e. exposes the data in derived 'Service' classes...have I missed the point somewhere?:]

```
//Important: You need to save the session!
authService.SaveSession(session, SessionExpiry);
```

// UPDATE *****

My AppHost has this:

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppDb"].ConnectionString;
container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(c => new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connectionString, SqlServerDialect.Provider));
container.Register<IUserAuthRepository>(c => new OrmLiteAuthRepository(c.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>()));

var authRepo = (OrmLiteAuthRepository)container.Resolve<IUserAuthRepository>();
```

Gavin's answer is very helpful but still is not able to give me the 'Db' object that gives the Ormlite methods.

I tried creating

```
protected ServiceStack.OrmLite.IDbConnectionFactory Db1 { get; set; }
```

and wiring it up in the CustomUserSession() constructor with this line:

```
this.Db1 = EndpointHost.AppHost.TryResolve<ServiceStack.OrmLite.IDbConnectionFactory>();
```

but it didnt work as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Resolve your database class/factory/repository however you like (assuming you've registered it with your IOC container).

```
public class CustomUserSession : AuthUserSession
{

    public CustomUserSession()
    {
        this.Log = LogManager.GetLogger(this.GetType());
        this.Repository = EndpointHost.AppHost.TryResolve<IRepository>();
    }

    protected IRepository Repository { get; set; }
    protected ILog Log { get; set; }

    public string CustomProperty { get; set; }

    public override void OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, IOAuthTokens tokens, Dictionary<string, string> authInfo)
    {

        this.CustomProperty = this.Repository.GetCustomProperty(session.UserAuthName);

        var otherRepository = authService.TryResolve<IOtherRepository>();
        session.Permissions.AddRange(otherRepository.GetPermissions(session.UserAuthId));

        // etc.....

        base.OnAuthenticated(authService, session, tokens, authInfo);

    }

    public override void OnRegistered(IServiceBase registrationService)
    {
        this.Log.WarnFormat(
            "OnRegistered - queue a registered event/email/notification");

        base.OnRegistered(registrationService);
    }

}
```

As far as calling `SaveSession`, IIRC it is required to persist changes, though this was when implementing an [AuthProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326502/servicestack-authentication-with-existing-database).

Comment: Thanks for tips Gavin...really helpful but still doesnt answer the original question of getting OrmLite native methods on a local object

Comment: I believe OrmLite is just extension methods on IDbConnection. As long as you have reference it ('using ServiceStack.OrmLite;') the methods should be available. You could just do something like '((Service)authService).Db.FirstOrDefault<MyTable>(x => x.Id == userId);'